# Java Object creation vs. String parsing

Tags: java, jsp, migration

I'm working on migrating a project which is very JSP-centric to using Velocity.  In many places the JSP pages were simply parsing strings to display various things.  This makes the JSP very ugly and difficult to maintain obviously.

I have modified the Controller for this class to do this work for me (i.e. creating a List of POJOs), then iterating over the pieces using velocity.  I have a feeling that it's going to come with heavy resistance.

I realize that creating the Object comes with overhead, but it makes our pages much easier to debug, write and use.  Besides the fact it separates the UI from the core logic of what is occurring in the background.  Not to mention our appservers are BORED.  The database is wincing in pain.  We are to see a tenfold increase in users (which could be why it was initially developed to parse the strings in the JSP & skip the object creation) -- this smells to me of premature optimization.

What are further arguments to support my claim that we should eat the cost associated with the object creation?

Comment: "this smells to me of premature optimization" - agreed. I mean, Java is an **Object Oriented** language. Why would someone want to avoid using objects? The JVM is optimized for these things.

Comment: if you know how JSP and the (f)ugly term called `pojo` works... then no need for the question. Object creation, while not free [a bit more expensive w/ any final fields], has a little cost. You shant put together database/jsp AND java object creation. Java does use a per thread small area and NON-Shared pointer to allocate new object, so it's almost like stack allocation (not really but cheaper than most c++ malloc impl)

Comment: At least they aren't doing JDBC calls inside of the JSP!  I'm very new to the group, so I just need to make sure that my bases are covered as I make these changes.

Comment: forgot that, parsing strings alone creates tons of other strings, java.lang.String is a full-blown object and has another object a `char[]` (that can be shared only if using String.substring) and 3 more `int`s.  Object creation of new strings is comparable to object creation of your own pojos (depends on the number of the fields)...

Comment: coming to the JSP, itself, means a hundreds (thousands more like) objects are created already. Putting an object into a java.util.HashMap allocates an object (not a good example but it still happens). Calling ReenttrantLock.lock() creates object(s) and so on. Do not be afraid of object creation, itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Object creation in Java was *somewhat* expensive, about 15 years ago. Java runtimes have a improved a lot since then. Nowadays, Java object creation is often faster than in C++.
- It was *never* so expensive that it would be a decisive factor in basic application design.
- Doing things in a JSP does *not* mean no (or even fewer) objects are created. Quite the opposite, most likely. JSPs are compiled to perfectly normal Java code that creates lots of objects.
- It sounds like your company needs to hire at least one person who actually understands how Java works ASAP.

Comment: *It sounds like your company needs to hire at least one person who actually understands how Java works ASAP*, many companies need that. and you have a wonderful answer (no +1, since i dont vote, but it well deserved)

Comment: @kelloti, adding more question marks makes a question more robust i presume? you can check a person profile to see the number of the cast votes. To answer, though and not be rude, no I don't. I see no single reason for.

Comment: @bestsss - (1) It shows you appreciate someone's answer. (2) It helps people easily weed out the bad answers and look straight to the good ones (the whole point of stack overflow). (3) it gives incentive for people to take their time in giving good answers

Comment: @kelloti, agree about (1) but disagree about (2) and (3). However, since i myself care little to none about the appreciation part... Actually I strongly disagree about the (2), many (if not most) people who can vote doesn't know the right answer which is a major issue. Anyways, I don't wish to go into some religious/political fight, so you can have your own way :)

Comment: @kelloti, if I need to show appreciation (which admittedly is exceptionally rare, but when it's due I do], I do exactly what I have done, I leave a non-anonymous comment.

Comment: @bestsss, see some discussion on voting.  You may find it interesting.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80368/why-vote-on-answers

Comment: @bestsss I want you to please imagine what SE would be like if there were no voting system. Then revisit the reasons why you "strongly disagree" that bubbling good answers to the top is a good thing.

Comment: @Corey, i always sort answers by activity, so it doesn't happen

Answer (score 5):

Object creation is cheap. Very cheap. And modern computers are fast. Very fast.

Do some simple profiling. See how long it takes to create a million of your POJOs. It'll be quite quick.

Comment: *See how long it takes to create a million of your POJOs*. this is a very unsound advice. Most people have absolutely no clue how to impl. a proper microbenchmark. Allocating a million of small objects can be quite different in a single threaded test than a multithreaded web/app-server

Comment: I'm so depressed. I wanted to have the accepted answer. Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

Maintenance - most dollars are spent maintaining software vs. developing.  If you make something easy to maintain and extend, it's a blessing.

It's generally frowned upon in this community to do any premature optimization.  What kind of hardware are you running on?  I imagine servers can handle your workload... I tend to like the idea of making it work well first, and then finding bottle necks.  You might find that object creation isn't the biggest problem when you profile it.